# Any way to send HTML element object from one BrowserWindow to another BrowserWindow in electron using IPC?

Tags: javascript, dom, electron, htmlelements

I can send string and object from one [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window) to another [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window) using [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) and [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) in [electronJS](https://www.electronjs.org)

the code:
**mainProcess.js:**

```
function createWindow1 () {
  window1 = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,height: 600})
  window1.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/window1.html`)
  window1.webContents.openDevTools()
  window1.on('closed', function () {
     window1 = null
  })
  return window1
}
function createWindow2 () {
  window2 = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 600})
  window2.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/window2.html`)
  window2.webContents.openDevTools()
  window2.on('closed', function () {
    window2 = null
  })
  return window2
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  window1 = createWindow1();
  window2 = createWindow2();

  ipcMain.on('nameMsg', (event, arg) => {
  console.log("name inside main process is: ", arg); // this comes form within window 1 -> and into the mainProcess
  event.sender.send('nameReply', { not_right: false }) // sends back/replies to window 1 - "event" is a reference to this chanel.
  window2.webContents.send( 'forWin2', arg ); // sends the stuff from Window1 to Window2.
});
```

**window1.html:**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <button type="button" id="sendName" >Send the name! </button>
</body>
<script>
   // You can also require other files to run in this process
   require('./window1.js')
</script>
```

**window1.js:**

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer

let name = document.getElementById('name');

ButtonSendName = document.getElementById('sendName');
ButtonSendName.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  ipcRenderer.send('nameMsg', name.value);
})

ipcRenderer.on('nameReply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // why/what is not right..
});
```

window2.html:

```
<body>
  <p id = "showName"></p>
</body>

<script>
  require('./window2.js')
</script>
```

**window2.js:**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

showName = document.getElementById('showName')
ipcRenderer.on('forWin2', function (event, arg){
  console.log(arg);
  showName.innerHTML = arg;
});
console.log("I'm Window2");
```

A demo would be better, but I don't know how to build an electron CodeBin app. This image gives you an idea:
[image]

This works nicely.

But I am not able to send DOM object (HTML element object) using this approch

`ipcRenderer.invoke('slideChange', document.getElementById('selectedSlide'))`

I am getting error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned.`

Is there any way to pass HTML element to another BrowserWindow using same machanism?

Comment: Why you would do that? You can interact with your other window using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using Electron, you can't send DOM objects between processes.

> Electron's IPC implementation uses the HTML standard Structured Clone Algorithm to serialize objects passed between processes, meaning that only certain types of objects can be passed through IPC channels.
>
> In particular, DOM objects (e.g. Element, Location and DOMMatrix), Node.js objects backed by C++ classes (e.g. process.env, some members of Stream), and Electron objects backed by C++ classes (e.g. WebContents, BrowserWindow and WebFrame) are not serializable with Structured Clone.

Ref: [Electron - Inter-Process Communication - Object serialization](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#object-serialization).